# How to check if the user possible choices contain results

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have this form with steps, on each step the form submits and return results via AJAX.

When the user selects the first step, the second step is activated and the user is presented with three options, those options may or may not contain further results depending on the user choice. The thing is I would like to limit the user possible choices on the second step depending if the choice contains results or not.

Basically I would need to run the queries beforehand and if they contain results then they should appear and if not they should not be visible.

```
$this->firstChoice = (int) \Input::get('first_choice');
$this->secondChoice = (int) \Input::get('second_choice');

$this->results = Class::with('relation');

if(isset($this->firstChoice ) && $this->firstChoice > 0) {
    $id = $this->firstChoice ;
    $this->results->whereHas('first-relationship', function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    })
}

if(isset($this->secondChoice ) && $this->secondChoice > 0) {
    $id = $this->secondChoice ;
    $this->results->whereHas('second-relationship', function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('id', $id);
    })
}

** before the second step is checked i need to run a query check on the second 
relationship and if the possible choice contains results then i need to show only those options **
```

I have tried something like this but with no success.

```
if($this->results->whereHas('second-relationship', function($q) {
     $q->where('id', 1);
})->count() > 0) {
    $newArray = ['push results here and then return it to the front end']
} // this repeated 3 times for the three possible choices

** ID = 1 for the first option id - i have tried it hard coded and also in a foreach loop
where the id's were dynamic but without any success **
```

The second I run the query to check if the choices have possible results the code breaks.

I would just like to know how to run the check for the users possible choice and their results.

How should i approach this problem, any help is greatly appreciated.

Coded in October CMS.

Comment: I have added answer but seems without your database schema its little difficult to predict complete solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, you need to make your all next step depending on the current selection.

> For Ex: the first step would be `CHOICES` which do have the next choices (I explain below).

Now, when the user selects and submits the result make ajax and present another form with `CHOICES` which do have the next choices.

```
// for OUR form NO. 1
// Retrieve all choose which has at lesat one choice
// this could be your `onShowFirstForm`
$choices = Choice::has('children')->get();

// NOW user select one of them
// for Next form prepare choices
// this could be your `onNextForm`
$choices = Choice::find($selectedChoiseId)->has('children')->fetch();

// and so on
// you can continue ... with this
```

Here is there is only one stop, AT some point you will get `$choices` will be blank as they can not have further `child` -> at that point you can just show message etc

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Hello Hardik, thanks for your reply, to be clearer i have a model that contains all the cohoices from the second step that i want to limit based on the first step selection, i show the model results on the onRender function ex; $this['results'] = Model::all(), i need to modify that variable and pass its results to a partial that i refresh on submit. I need to know a way how to run a query on the $this->results collection with all possible choices on the second step based on what the user will choose on the first step. I hope that I am clear enough  of what i want to accomplice. Thank you.

Comment: ok this problem is regarding database/modeling OR partial rendering side

Comment: The problem is that I can't find a way to run a check query that checks if the $this->results collection has results based on the three possible choices in the second step, the rendering of the results i can achieve with no problems after i have the desired results. In my opinion I need to check if that collection has results and if it has then populate an array which later ill return as a partial refresh.

Comment: The simplest way to put my question in is the following: I want to check if a collection relationship has any results based on id's (id = 1, 2 and 3), and if that collection  has result then that a new collection and push the results there.
When the first step is chosen then the second step has choice 1, 2 and 3, choice 1 has no items when chosen, choices 2 nave 3 have.
Take those choices and put them in a collection, and later on I will show them to the front end.